# Amazon S3 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: amazon-s3

I setup a big file upload via php to Amazon S3.

The problem it's for big file I get sometimes : 504 Gateway Timeout Error.

For small files it's working perfect. I don't understand how to increase the idle time.

Thank you !

Comment: 2020 and I still have this issue. Any resolution?